# Does SOLR 4 know if a document has changed on an update?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am designing a system to index meta-data. As the full data comes in I will extract several pieces of information (meta-data) and create a SOLR document and add that document to SOLR. When a notification comes that the full data has changed, I will extract the meta-data again and then update the SOLR index. The meta-data might not actually change. If I send an update to SOLR 4 will it detect that the document hasn't changed and do nothing? Do I need to get the document from SOLR and compare the values myself and only call update if indeed values have changed in the SOLR document?

Comment: It can't possibly know in the general case. I don't see how it matters anyway...

Comment: Updating an index usually isn't free. Our current system takes hundreds of updates a second to nearly two billion documents. Updating a document that would cause something to be re-indexed is expensive for us now. Querying the index, getting the original document, then comparing the values is less expensive than just doing an update every time. This is because often the meta-data hasn't changed. If SOLR can do this, or automatically does a get and a compare for an existing document I would like to know.

Comment: See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch

Comment: Thank you. I have read that several times and understand there are soft commits. If it wasn't for that I wouldn't be considering the use of SOLR. So, I take it that I should query, compare, and update only if my SOLR document's fields have changed.

Comment: I think just updating without querying first will be faster...

Comment: Thank you. When I benchmark SOLR 4, I wanted to make sure I am doing it in the way that is best.